# Meandering Array going out of index, but works fine in some cases

Tags: python

I am trying to meander an array.

For example if I have:

```
     a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to have an output like this:

```
     output = [6,1,5,2,4,3]
```

What I'm doing is that I want largest number, follow by smallest number, follow by second largest number, follow by second smallest number etc.

I have a code, but doesn't work for all cases.

Here is a copy of my code

```
def meanderingArray(arr) : 
    n = len(arr)
    arr.sort() 
  
    tempArr = [0] * (n + 1) 
  
    ArrIndex = 0

    i = 0
    j = n-1
      
    while(i <= n // 2 or j > n // 2 ) : 
      
        tempArr[ArrIndex] = arr[j] 
        ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
        tempArr[ArrIndex] = arr[i] 
        ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
        i = i + 1
        j = j - 1
    for i in range(0, n) : 
        arr[i] = tempArr[i] 
    return arr
      

meanderingArray([22231,44423,66574,-14122,-12322,14476])


IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-8993ecc448e2> in <module>
----> 1 meanderingArray([22231,44423,66574,-14122,-12323,14476])

<ipython-input-26-24690fd05e2d> in meanderingArray(arr)
     14         tempArr[ArrIndex] = arr[j]
     15         ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
---> 16         tempArr[ArrIndex] = arr[i-1]
     17         ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
     18         i = i + 1

IndexError: list assignment index out of range


Anything I can adjust in the code?

Thanks
```

Comment: Sorry for my wordings. Corrected already. What do you think I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In Python, these are called *lists*, not "arrays".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work when the array has odd length.  You will be grabbing the middle element twice, once using `i` and once using `j`, and then appending it twice.   It would have been more obvious what was broken if instead you wrote:

```
tempArray = []
while.....
    tempArray.append(arr[j])
    tempArray.append(arr[i])
    ...
```

rather than getting an AIOOB exception, you would have seen that the middle element was added twice.  You need to abort out of the early if i==j

Answer (score 2):

I would do this much more simply, by using slicing:

```
def meander(l):
    l.sort()
    odd_count = len(l) // 2
    even_count = len(l) - odd_count
    l[::2], l[1::2] = l[:-(even_count + 1):-1], l[:odd_count]
```

(Since the list is modified in-place, the Python convention is *not* to return the value.)

Explanation: we determine how many odd and even indices there are (since the list is 0-indexed, the first position is even), and then simultaneously put the appropriate values into the even positions (by taking them backwards from the end) and odd positions (taking them forwards from the front).

Comment: That simultaneous assignment via slices is fascinatingly beautiful. Even if you wanted the function to return instead of modify in-place, it still seems like the most elegant method to me—just initialize a new list and slice-assign to that.

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  I was torn between answering poster's question "Why doesn't this work?" and showing the zipper solution.

Comment: The reverse slicing doesn't look that simple to me. I'd maybe do `l[1::2], l[::2] = l[:half], l[half:][::-1]`.

Comment: Or I guess with your way I'd do `l[:~even_count:-1]`. Though that's even less simple unless you're used to using `lst[~i]` for reverse indexing.

Comment: Reverse indexing has always seemed trickier than it ought to be. I do like the double slice trick.

Answer (score 1):

For an efficient solution you can zip the sequence of `a` in reverse order with `a` itself, chain the resulting sequence of 2-tuples with `itertools.chain.from_iterable`, and slice it to the length of `a` with `itertools.islice`:

```
from itertools import chain, islice
list(islice(chain.from_iterable(zip(reversed(a), a)), len(a)))
```

This returns:

```
[6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. How did I not think of that?

Comment: Yeah, I was sure you could find it, that's why I didn't post it at first. Btw, a similar one, even happens to be exactly equally long :-): `list(map(next, islice(cycle((reversed(a), iter(a))), len(a))))`. But I like the zip+chain one better.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward fix is just to not execute the problem line if it is going to produce an error.  If that's the case, then i == j and you've already moved the value in question.  Here's your whole code with the one fixed line:

```
def meanderingArray(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    arr.sort()

    tempArr = [0] * (n + 1)

    ArrIndex = 0

    i = 0
    j = n - 1

    while (i <= n // 2 or j > n // 2):
        print("{} {} {}".format(i, j, ArrIndex))
        tempArr[ArrIndex] = arr[j]
        ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
        if ArrIndex < len(tempArr):
            tempArr[ArrIndex] = arr[i]
        ArrIndex = ArrIndex + 1
        i = i + 1
        j = j - 1
    for i in range(0, n):
        arr[i] = tempArr[i]
    return arr


print(meanderingArray([22231, 44423, 66574, -14122, -12322, 14476]))
```